# Why does the Chromium browser just flash (see gif) when I start it? How can I fix it?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, chromium, web-browsers

When I start the Chromium browser on my RPi it just flashes (no nav bar ever appears).

Here's a gif (video) of what it does:
[image: RPi Chromium browser flashes]

I'm connecting via VNC.

**Details of My Installation**

- Distributor ID: Raspbian
- Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
- Release:        11
- Codename:       bullseye

**Things I've Tried**

1. Uninstalling / installing Chromium
2. Ran Dillo browser - it will run
3. Updated all software

**UPDATED**

I just hooked up the RPi to my KVM -- had to pull plugs from my Mac Mini.
I started it up and started Chromium and it loaded up with no problem.  Chromium was in an odd state - console window open and no page loaded.

I then went to my Windows 10 laptop (which I've been using all along to VNC to the RPi) and when I connected I set a home page to load automatically just to make sure things would be "normal"

Everything looked fine through VNC while the RPi was connected to KVM and I was seeing everything normal on the connected physical monitor too.

**Things Went Bonkers Again**

I shutdown the RPi, disconnected the KVM and plugged the RPi in again to allow it to restart.

When it came up I VNC'd to it and started Chromium and it is flashing again.

**Guessing - It's Video Driver**

So with this, I'm guessing there is something wonky with the video driver or VNC video settings.

**Update 2**

I started Chromium from the console and I see the following:

[image: console errors from chromium]

Then after those lines you just continually see that the browser tries to refresh

[image: browser refresh bogus]

Do you know of any way to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Does this also happen when you try this locally with connected monitor, keyboard and mouse?

Comment: what does the browser window look like after you start it? ... please add a picture ... the video does not stop at the end result

Comment: @jsotola  It never stops.  It continues in that loop forever.  Seriously.  Thanks for asking so I could clarify.  

Comment: @Bodo I connected a KVM and Chromium started up fine. I VNC'd to it while connected to phsyical monitor and Chromium was still fine.  After shutting down, removing KVM and then connecting only via VNC I see the Chromium flashing again.

Comment: please copy the text and paste it into your question ... do not post a picture of text ... use the `{}` button to format the text as *code*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made two changes to RPi Configuration:

1. Set video for headless operation
2. Turned off advanced GL features (set basic feature).

Chromium loads fine and works now from VNC connection.

Comment: I have the same behavior using VNC. Where / how do you make these changes?

Comment: @float You'll need to run the rpi configuration tool. Here's the link that will walk you through that: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html
Check out "Interfacing Options"

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by running this command to install Firefox ESR:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr
```

And using Firefox instead of Chromium

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem. It doesn't happen when an HDMI monitor is connected, so a workaround is to always enable the HDMI output even when nothing is connected by editing the /boot/config.txt file:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

(Or your favorite text editor instead of nano.) Then un-comment the line 'hdmi_force_hotplug=1' by removing the # at the start.

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

You may also need to set the default HDMI screen resolution, un-comment and update these lines:

```
  hdmi_group=1
  hdmi_mode=4
```

HDMI mode 4 is 1280x720, 16 is 1920x1080. You can look up other resolutions. Then save the file & reboot.